# Bounty Expiration

Tags: support, reputation, bounty

What is the meaning of *Bounty expiration*. After the expiration, offered reputation will be refund? If no, then who will get the offered reputation?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

See [How does the bounty system work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/16065)

When the bounty expires, the reputation is not refunded; a bounty is the price of getting attention for a question.

**If** an answer qualifies (posted after the bounty was started, with at least 2 upvotes, has the most upvotes), it'll be assigned half the bounty amount at some point after the bounty has expired.

If an answer was posted during the bounty period and was marked as accepted, then that answer is assigned the full bounty.

If you are talking about [the bounty *you* offered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22735041/how-to-remove-fragment-layout-in-beginning-of-creating-a-new-app-in-adt), there is currently no qualifying answers. If one of the answers reaches a score of 2 in the next 23 hours, it'll be awarded +25 points if you don't assign the bounty manually.

Comment: What are the chances of this changing? It doesn't seem right that bounties against popular tags get much more exposure for the same "price". I just had a bounty run its course without getting a single answer…

Comment: No, this is not going to change. You got much more attention than other questions *within the same tag*. You cannot compare a question in a less popular tag with one in, say, the top 20; there are just fewer people that can answer.