# What happens to unawarded bounties when a question is deleted?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, reputation, bounty, deleted-questions

Based on this question ([Bounty Expiration](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251699/bounty-expiration)) I understand that I am not supposed to have my reputation "refunded" when a bounty goes unanswered.

However, I observed the following, and consequently I'm wondering if it's a bug.

- I posted a question ([#24740675](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24740675/how-to-document-functional-requirements-for-stochastic-probabalistic-systems)).
- No answers
- I offered a bounty of 150 (my reputation was debited)
- One user posted an answer but subsequently deleted it (I did not have time to read, vote or accept it)
- The bounty period expired (no current answers)
- The bounty grace period expired (no current answers)
- I deleted my original question
- Some minutes later, I noticed that my reputation was back up, the -150 reputation debit was not in my reputation history, and several positive reputation events that I had already seen previously had been marked as unread.

Comment: Did you lose the points you gained when the bounty question was upvoted? Or was it a strict +150?

Comment: It seems question upvote credits were also withdrawn from my balance upon deleting the question

Comment: I was up to post a duplicate of this, because the title is such poor. What about changing it to *If a question gets deleted, are unawarded bounties given back?* and adding it to the FAQ?

Comment: At the time of writing the question, I didn't know what factors were important to the functionality in question, but now that the answer has been provided, I think this is a good idea.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Bounty awards and costs are all refunded when a question is deleted. If you were to ever undelete your question in the future, the 150 reputation would be subtracted from your account again.

Comment: Ok, I guess I can't complain about that :)

Comment: If that's case what's to stop you asking a question with a huge bounty, getting a solution then (awarding)/deleting your question to get your reputation back?

Comment: @Liath: there are conditions on being able to delete a question, though I do not know them off-hand. You might not be able to delete a question with un-deleted answers for example.

Comment: @Liath The answerer will post here on meta or flag the question, moderators will find out the deleted question and undelete it (and probably take other actions such as a temporary ban).  Also, I'm pretty sure you cannot delete a question that has a positive scored answer, which is very likely if you open a 500 rep bounty.

Comment: Upvoted answers prevent question deletion.  An answer to a bounty question might be well thought-out and might be upvoted fairly quickly.

Comment: This would seem to be a case where submitting a new question would be better than editing and undeleting the old question, if new information was discovered to help with the solution.  A new bounty could be added as well.