# Is it possible to search my deleted questions?

Tags: support, deleted-questions, deleted-answers

I tried to find a Q&A of mine that I found extremely useful (I even awarded the answer a bounty if I remember correctly). However I'm unable to find it.

It seems that it's been removed, and it's been more than 60 days as I am unable to find it in my 'Recent Deleted Questions'. I definitely asked the question as I found the applicable function that the answer to the question provided (I didn't attribute- *bad cybermonkey, bad!*):

```
Len = function(msg, length, dir)
    --We can 'pad' stuff in messages to make everything neat.
    if not msg or not length then
        return "Unknown";
    end
    local msgC = msg:gsub("$%d", "");
    if (dir == "l") then
        return string.rep(" ", length - #msgC)..msg
    else
        return msg..string.rep(" ", length - #msgC)
    end
end
```

The function has been modified but however the main `if` block is *not* my code as I always use semicolons (the code in the `if (dir == "l") then` block does not). I searched for snippets of the code and found no matches.

I have also tried the [Stack Exchange Data Explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/) to no effect, and even visited my reputation history, retrieved all the -2 reputation events for my profile, and had PHP retrieve the page title for each question ID (*I stopped it after a minute since I realised that requesting 1,100+ pages in quick succession would likely be classed as abuse*).

I also realised that the above method would not be effective anyhow as the Q&A was deleted more than 60 days ago (anywhere between 60 days and ***two years***- two years as that's when I last programmed in Lua). I I could use the [SE data dump](https://archive.org/details/stackexchange) but I do not want to download the post history and post databases as it would simply be a waste of bandwidth if I couldn't find anything useful (almost 15GB for the posts and almost 9GB for the history).

---

I *could* ask a new question duplicating the question I asked and the answer, but I *really* would like the original Q&A to be restored. I don't even know why it was deleted in the first place... I remember it as a high-quality Q&A that was extremely useful to me and (probably) to others.

The question was tagged [lua](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/lua) (as the programming language) and the title was probably something along the lines of 'How can I pad a string?' or similar.

I also most certainly didn't have it dissociated and nor did I delete it myself.

---

Is there really no reliable way I can search my own deleted questions & answers?

Comment: If you get 10K rep you can search for it in the UI, barring that only a moderator can find it for you currently.

Comment: I just sent an email using the 'Contact Us' form regarding this (requested them to locate it and give me the question ID or URL, so I am able to view it and find out its reason for deletion), so I'm hoping that the reply will shed some light onto the situation.

Comment: Wow, you have a lot of deleted questions :) trying to find it

Comment: I cannot find a question resembling that linked to your account; is it possible you had another account? can you give me any date clues?

Comment: @MarcGravell I remember having an earlier account under my email address (my current one used a different email originally, then I changed it to the same email as my earlier account), but am unable to access it due to my email address for my current account being identical. I haven't used it for a couple of years, and don't think I asked such a question on it.

Comment: I've checked everything against your account; I've checked all questions (by anoyone, deleted or not) in the [tag:lua] tag with "pad" in the title (mostly "notepad" and "joypad"); I've double-checked all your bounties... I can't see anything similar...

Comment: @RobertLongson you can only search your *own* deleted posts, not anyones, and judging by latest comment the account is not accessible anymore.

Comment: @MarcGravell Weird, it might've been under another account or completely destroyed. I'll do another Q&A to replace it, thanks for your help!

Comment: @Braim I'm afraid I lack the precience required to know he had two accounts before the comment that said so.

Answer (score 23):

It's not obvious at all, but you can do this with some creative advanced search if you have 10,000 reputation. Note that this will show you (the reader) your deleted stuff, not the OP's specifically

[View your deleted questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3Ame+deleted%3A1+is%3Aquestion) (`user:me deleted:yes is:question`)

[View your deleted answers](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3Ame+deleted%3A1+is%3Aanswer) (`user:me deleted:yes is:answer`)

Comment: If you have less than <10k rep, this won't work. It's a [privilege](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools): *You also have a new search operator available to find your own deleted posts: deleted:1.*

Comment: Although this answer is correct, it does not apply to those below 10k reputation.

Comment: Hmm, so it does. That stinks. I thought you could view your own at least

Comment: Yeah, perhaps it might be a good idea to post a feature request for it on here. You can see your own deleted questions and answers if you have the direct link to it, after all.

Comment: I'm over 10k. Thanks for posting this I didn't know it was possible.

Comment: How did you figure out "delete:yes" is a search option? I don't see it at http://stackoverflow.com/help/searching.

Comment: @RSahu Interesting. That page doesn't have it. Do a search (any term) and then click the Advanced Search Tips on the right hand side. It's listed there

Comment: Documenting software consistently has never been easy.

Comment: I opened a [bug post about it](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/327273/advanced-search-tips-out-of-sync-with-search-help)

Comment: @RSahu - The note about deleted:1 is also on the [10k privileges page](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools)

Comment: @cybermonkey the feature request exists, and was denied 6 years ago. The reasons given at the time are no longer valid, but that hasn't led to any movement.

Comment: This is one of the most useful answers on MSO :-)

Answer (score 5):

### Via your list of deleted questions

It's in your profile. Click on "all questions" and at the bottom there will be a list of your [deleted questions](https://stackoverflow.com/users/deleted-questions/current). You are only shown the title but hopefully you don't have too many deleted questions and have at least an idea of what it might have been titled.

10k users can find these directly in search with `deleted:yes`.

### Via the bounty

> I even awarded the answer a bounty if I remember correctly

Have you tried searching for the bounty rep change? There would [TWO events](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/267033/6083675), and you probably have few bounty events overall.

You may be able to use your browser's search functions and just go through all the pages.

Remember to <sub><sub>[image: show removed posts]</sub></sub>

Answer (score 0):

This is a request by many people [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2645/show-all-of-my-question-answers-to-me-even-if-they-are-deleted).

For some reason they are hidden from you unless you have 10k reputation.

(As a workaround - you can check your browser's history. Deleted questions *can* be viewed if you have a link to them.)