# Advanced Search Tips out of sync with Search Help

Tags: bug, search, help-center

So I shared a useful searching tip over [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/327259/2370483), which prompted a comment that it doesn't appear on the [search help page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/searching). Specifically the `deleted` option is missing, while it's present in the Advanced Search Tips (can see them on any search page). There could be more as well. It needs to be audited to have these tips added (or at least accessible)

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The option is most likely missing from the help pages because it does not work for users under 10k rep.

According to Jon Clements, the feature was originally intended to be mod-only:

> I think the reason it isn't shown is that the `deleted:` search operator was originally only meant to be available to diamond mods and is documented elsewhere

I don't think that the help page is able to change based off a user's rep (although there are more pages for [mods](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/198350)). So there are two choices: show it or don't. Showing it would benefit the small population of 10k+ users that still read the help pages, but it has the strong possibility of confusing all the lower rep users.

Once you reach 10k, you should be able to navigate around the site, and get to the privilege page [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools) where the feature is documented.

---

As a user without the privilege, I see this:

> [image: No deleted option]

If I try to search with the `deleted:1` option, it is ignored completely:

> [image: not deleted question]

Note that it is showing only my NOT deleted posts, such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36184124).

Comment: I think the reason it isn't shown is that the `delete:` search operator was originally only meant to be available to diamond mods and is documented elsewhere.