# Retrieving Answers I have Deleted

Tags: support, deleted-answers

Sometimes I post an answer to a question and the community points out that I totally misinterpreted the question, so I delete my answer.

Later on, I get *deleter's remorse.* I want to go back to the answer and either fix it or retrieve it for other purposes. If I go back to answers in my profile page, the deleted stuff is missing!

Is there a way to easily get back to my deleted stuff, or should I bookmark before deleting?

Comment: You may search for `user:me is:a deleted:1`, but I'm not sure whether it will return *recently* deleted answers.

Comment: I just tested the query above after having done something similar (unwittingly), and it does seem to pick up answers deleted in the last 5 minutes.

Comment: @vaultah Thanks a lot for the query!

Comment: @vaultah   Many thanks! ..................Clearly I must study using the **Search Box.**

Comment: Sadly, it doesn't work for users with less than 10k reputation http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/327238/is-it-possible-to-search-my-deleted-questions/327259#comment363436_327259

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have >10k reputation, you can [search your deleted posts](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools). This would be the link for deleted answers, as noted by @vaultah:

https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3Ame+is%3Aa+deleted%3A1

If you have less than <10k reputation, you can only view deleted answers which were posted in the past 60 days. To do so, replace my user ID (4751173) with yours in the following link:

https://stackoverflow.com/users/recently-deleted-answers/4751173

There's another slightly convoluted workaround which works for sub-10k users and posts older than 60 days, but it requires the post to be voted on. In that case, you'll be able to find it via your reputation history by carefully looking at reputation changes from removed posts. I have described that procedure [here on Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/333518/295232).