# Ambiguous reason for a helpful flag

Tags: discussion, flags, bounty, helpful-flags

Here is the flag related to this question: [Resize with scale - convert jquery to React JS](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63181212/8620333)

[image]

I don't really understand the comment. Why should we allow the bounty to run because there is an answer? An off-topic question is an off-topic question, no?

I was also going to flag this one: [How to set all element to left side with window scroll-down?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63267297/8620333) for almost the same reason (Probably I should not?)

<sub>Let's hope they will hurry with this: [Allow bountied questions to be closed by regular users](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/399013/8620333) because the bountied off-topic questions are increasing...</sub>

Comment: [Why cannot this question with an open bounty be closed?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/199190)

Comment: If an answer was posted after the bounty started, the standing policy is to let the bounty end. If a question should be closed, it should have been done during the two day pre-bounty waiting period.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand the context. Which sort of flag was it / what was the purpose of the flag, that it was marked as helpful?

Comment: @RobertSsupportsMonicaCellio it was a custom Mod flag

Comment: @SamuelLiew: _"If a question should be closed, it should have been done during the two day pre-bounty waiting period"_ -- I agree with that. However, the problem is that Stack Overflow is not very good at closing questions that need to be closed. So without some kind of backstop, we are left with the current situation of a question that _should_ already have been closed but which was not, and then subsequently winds up rewarding the author of the off-topic question with an off-topic answer.

Answer (score 33):

The reasoning behind this is that OP spent 100 reputation points to get an answer. An answer was provided. If mods refund the bounty now then OP would keep the reputation and benefit from receiving the answer. Sometimes it's better to let the bounty be awarded and delete the question immediately after. The 100 reputation will then be irrevocably spent and the answerer will not keep the bounty either.

Bounty is used to attract attention to a question. If the question is off-topic that doesn't mean that the bounty failed in its purpose. However, if the bounty didn't manage to attract any answers yet, it would make sense to refund and delete the question immediately.

Comment: then something need to be changed. We should be able to not refund the bounty. I don't see why we need to refund the bounty in such case. We should give Mod the ability to not refund the bounty because actually all situations are benefical to the OP.

Comment: even if we massively downvote the question, the Rep will be back after the delete so we can clearly do nothing when a bounty is added. We can simply hope to catch it before an answer is added which *impossible*

Comment: If I understand correctly, the reason the bounty question isn't closed is because if the bounty is refunded to the OP, then it's unfair to the answerer. Since when has SO been about fairness? The answerer deserves it, because he answered a bad question. This would discourage people from doing so, actually, so the question's bounty should be deleted.

Comment: @10Rep No, not the answerer. If we close and delete the question then the answerer doesn't get any reputation from it. We want the person who placed the bounty to lose their reputation. They have already spent it and gotten what they need, so mods shouldn't refund it back.

Comment: @Dharman Ok, I understand. In that case, then why not end the bounty and not refund the bounty manually? Do mods have tools for that?

Comment: @TemaniAfif I agree it is difficult to catch it in the first two days, but you can set a reminding and come back to it once the bounty is over. Then flag and ask moderators to delete the question. This will nullify all reputation changes, except for the person who placed the bounty.

Comment: @10Rep Mods can only refund the bounty. They can't end it. If they were to refund the bounty now, then OP would have gotten what they wanted for free. There is no way close the question without giving the reputation points back to the person who placed the bounty unless the bounty is awarded to someone. Mods can't award the bounty.

Comment: @Dharman But that would be a good feature, right? This way it would save a lot of work, and you could close bountied questions. I'll place a feature request if you agree.

Comment: By and large, feature requests don't get implemented, so we work with what we have. And if I was going to choose one feature request, it wouldn't be allowing mods to cancel bounties without refunding. It would simply be to let the community close bountied questions by consensus.

Comment: I should also note it doesn't make sense to cancel a bounty when the bounty has nearly run out. I've declined them when it's day 5 of 7. Even if there's no answers, you're getting the benefit of raised exposure.

Comment: "The 100 reputation will then be irrevocably spent and the answerer will not keep the bounty either." that's not true. A deletion by a moderator would revert all votes/bounties. If you want to take away the reputation that posted the bounty, you need to keep the question for at least 60 days!!

Comment: @Braiam Not sure if I made a grammatical typo or if I can't understand your comment. Can you explain it? I meant that if the bounty is awarded and then the whole question is deleted the user who got the bounty will not retain the reputation points.

Comment: @Dharman "The 100 reputation will then be irrevocably spent" this part here isn't true. The user that placed the bounty would be refunded by deletion. See https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/243438/213575

Comment: Here's a [better link](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/267032/what-happens-to-unawarded-bounties-when-a-question-is-deleted), explicitly showing an example of the bounty cost being refunded on question deletion. This answer's claim appears to be wrong. Dharman, do you have a source for your claim?

Comment: @Braiam the question is deleted now, we can see what is happening

Comment: @TemaniAfif do you have a link to the user? Probably good idea posting what happened to the reputation.

Comment: @Braiam here is the OP: https://stackoverflow.com/users/592638/dude245?tab=profile and the user who answered: https://stackoverflow.com/users/10472451/joshlucpoll

Comment: @CodyGray can you confirm that the bounty was *lost*? no refund was done. There is a confusion in the above comments. Maybe because the answer was deleted first and not the whole question/answer.

Comment: If the target is to make the settler bounty lose rep it seems like a tragedy. The only downside is time, commitment and effort of the answerer

Comment: @Gad that's why we should NEVER answer off-topic question.

Comment: @Temani I'm sorry, I don't really understand the question you're asking me. I suppose you're making Braiam's point, that deleting the Q&A will also remove the bounty? Yes, that's true. But closure is very different from deletion. Do not expect that flagging a bountied question as being in need of closure is in any way equivalent to requesting that the question be deleted.

Comment: @CodyGray We simply want a confirmation that in this particular case, the bounty was not refuned after the deletion. I don't see any +100 in the OP account, so I suppose it's the case? some of the comments here are claiming that the deletion will automatically refund the bounty.

Comment: @CodyGray I think the question was whether if the bounty was awarded and then the whole question deleted, would the person who placed the bount get the reputation back.

Comment: @Temani Yes, the deletion of the question refunded the bounty to the asker, who had placed the 100-point bounty. They got that 100 reputation back. They also got back the reputation that they had lost from downvotes (28 downvotes, at a cost of -2 for each, which is a total of 56 reputation points; 156 reputation points were refunded to the asker upon deletion of the question, and that extra 100 comes from the bounty).

Comment: @CodyGray so what's the point of waiting until the bounty ends to close the question like I was suggested in the flag comment? why not closing the question when facing such flag?

Comment: Because deletion is different from closing. It was *deletion* that refunded the bounty, not the fact that it was closed.